# Does 64-bit translation and transformation slow down the engine significantly?

Tags: rendering, precision

So, how does one go with rendering world space calculated in 64-bit? How can that even work? GPUs can use Double Precision, but significantly slower than FP32. 
How can one achieve world space coordinates using 64-bits and then render it on consumer GPUs?

e.g.: Star Citizen and No Man's Sky claim 64-bit world coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

By handling your game mechanics in 64bit but then convert the coordinates to a local 32bit coordinate system when passing coordinates to the 3d rendering API. The origin of that local coordinate system should be either centered around the player or be a point nearby, so that objects close by are rendered with maximum precision. Nobody will notice when objects which are far away (like other stars) have a lower rendering precision.

Keep in mind that all you need to pass to the rendering engine per object and frame is its model-view matrix (which encodes the current position, rotation and scale), which is just 16 numbers you need to convert. The bulk of the floating-point calculation the GPU has to handle is sending all the vertices of the 3d model through that matrix. The vertices for each 3d model only need to be transferred to the GPU once. And considering that they are relative to the origin of the 3d mesh, there is very little reason to use 64bit vertex coordinates.

There are also situations where you want to use GPU acceleration for things which are usually considered game mechanics. Complex physics simulations or particle systems are a common example. But usually you only simulate them when they are close to the player. There is little reason in calculating the particles of a coronal mass ejection of a star at the other end of the galaxy.That means you can simulate these in a local coordinate system which uses 32bit as well.

Comment: Why does Star Citizen claim that to be revolutionary, while there are multiple solutions that implement localized relative systems?

Comment: @FabijanLetekovic Because it sounds good in marketing.

Answer (score 2):

Only coordinates (position) needs higher precision storage for game physics.

The GPU only needs to know everything relative to the camera (the screen) in order to render and does not necessarily needs to calculate physics so you can convert all the 64bits positions to 32bit camera-relative positions before feeding them to the GPU.

### Physics are another story:

Even 64 bit floats are not precise enough if you're walking on planets with the local star as the world origin.

You absolutely have to use a localized coordinate system for a space exploration game that lets you land and walk. You also need different systems for on-planet and off-planet physics.

This means at the game logic (CPU) level your coordinates, including the camera, are relative to a local reference point: the current planet's center (planetary exploration), the current solar system's center (local space travel), or the galaxy center (inter-planetary travel).

But this makes it somewhat more difficult to use the Engine's built-in collision and particle systems. You have to give the game engine everything in the local coordinate system and do conversions when switching areas and scales.

### Why is just switching to 64bits not enough:

If you're using the sun as the origin (zero):

- 64bits floats (doubles) have 53bits of precisions. (2^53 = 9.007199255×10¹⁵)
- Pluto is at 5,906,380,000,000 meters from the sun on average.
- 9.007199255×10¹⁵÷5906380000000 = 1/1525th of a meter of **precision (0.6mm, 0.024")**

That means that on Pluto with 64bit floats **any movement in a single frame smaller than 0.3mm** (0.6mm/2) will be **rounded down to zero** and any movement between 0.3mm and 0.6mm will be rounded up to 0.6mm and so on.

While this may still be fine for rendering this is not enough for physics and collisions.

If our minimum speed is 0.3mm **per frame** and that gets rounded up to 0.6mm this means that at just 60 frames per second:

0.3mm * 60 fps * 60 seconds * 60 minutes = 0.0648 kmh (0.04mph)

Gets rounded up to double this speed.

Assuming an acceptable error is a very forgiving 5% (1/20th) in order for movement to be visually tolerable this means the minimum acceptable speed would be 2.592kph (1.61mph).

Keep in mind a 5% error is still very perceivable.

Even on Earth movements would still look very coarse and collisions glitch due to rounding errors will be plentiful if the coordinate system's origin is the sun.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. So, they use what we all would use. I was under impression there is some kind of a revolutionary algorithm I was not aware of.

Comment: Well phrased! A related problem is when using a fp32 physics solver and having hugely heavy objects, like ships floating with buoyancy vectors at calm water.. Despite executing the calculation close to the zero domain, it's hard to get the smallest, finest movement - it either freezes or advances/rotates with a "fixed" minimum speed. Invoking other, irregular forces, like waves, tends to help a bit. The disadvantage of using someone elses code, as the solver may internally eg. calculate in a dumb order, struggling values to death :-). Roughly, fp32/64 have 7/14 significant digits.